# how to conditionally run sql scripts in wix

Tags: wix

I have 2 sql scripts, one is for fresh install and the other one is for updates. I want this installer to automatically check for the existance of the database.

Pseudo code:

```
IF (database exists)
{
    call 'UpdateDatabase' script
}
ELSE
{
    call 'CreateDatabase' script
}
```

Product.wxs

```
<sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlDatabase' Database='master' Server='.'
  CreateOnInstall='yes' DropOnUninstall='no' ContinueOnError='yes'>
  <sql:SqlScript Id='CreateDatabase' BinaryKey='CreateDatabase' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
  <sql:SqlScript Id='UpdateDatabase' BinaryKey='UpdateDatabase' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
</sql:SqlDatabase>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it. It's `ExecuteOnReinstall`. Works as expected.

```
<sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlDatabase' Database='master' Server='.'
  CreateOnInstall='yes' DropOnUninstall='no' ContinueOnError='yes'>
  <sql:SqlScript Id='CreateDatabase' BinaryKey='CreateDatabase' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
  <sql:SqlScript Id='UpdateDatabase' BinaryKey='UpdateDatabase' ExecuteOnReinstall='yes' />
</sql:SqlDatabase>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no built in facility that I know for this.  You would need to build a custom action.

You can set a property in custom action if a database exists or not and
based on its value, do a condition check call the script accordingly.